# MySQL server slow due to too many information_schema queries

Tags: mysql

Recently our server has been slow due to too many slow `information_schema` queries, which I am unable to kill. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

These queries are taking over an hour to run each.

What is causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: sorry , nobody can help ?

Comment: this problem related munin monitoring software . I disable MySQL plugin and resolved.